# ETH stuck in MIST (MAC)

Tags: ether, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet, macos

i have a big problem i can't solve myself.

my parents bought eth a while ago and stored it on their (old) mac (mist wallet).

the wallet wasn't updated half a year or something. unfortunately the mac has no more storage to further update the blocks.

i tried to update the version of mist wallet with little success. i still can't send the eth. i also tried to link the wallet with meta mask. from what i know i need the private key to do so. i found three private keys, but i don't know how to open/read the data.

if i erase the (hidden) geth data, will that help my case in moving the eth?

what can i do from here? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make backup of ~/Library/Ethereum/keystore, it where your private keys stored. I would recommend then delete ~/Library/Ethereum/geth folder with block data to free disk space. Then you can install newest version of Mist and use Develop-> "Sync with Light client (beta)" for fast sync

Comment: thx! i type that in TERMINAL, right? i just back up all three. i just hope the files i found are the files i am looking for. 
if i erase geth fully, the wallet should be intact, right?

Comment: wallet file should look something like  UTC--2018-02-28T14-01-41.083026654Z--<wallet address>. You could check on https://etherscan.io wallet ETH balance . To remove ~/Library/Ethereum/geth folder you can run command "rm -rf ~/Library/Ethereum/geth" in  terminal. Please make sure that you have backup of wallet files

Comment: thx a lot! cant upvote :/